# JWT token not yet valid

Tags: angular, jwt, google-signin

I've got a google sign in button in my angular web app.
After a successful sign in, I store the user profile and id-token.
The id-token is set in each request header I send to my custom api.

I'm currently getting 2 issues with the code below:

```
onGoogleSignInSuccess(event: GoogleSignInSuccess) {
var profile = event.googleUser.getBasicProfile();
var id_token = event.googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;

// store google user data in local storage
localStorage.setItem('googleUserProfile', JSON.stringify(profile));
localStorage.setItem('googleIdToken', JSON.stringify(id_token));

// check user's email address exist in Felix
this.userService.getUserByEmail(profile.getEmail()).subscribe(InUser => {
  this.globalService.setCurrentUser(InUser);
  this.router.navigate(['companylist']);
}, error => {
  this.errorLoggingIn = true;
  this.errorCode = error.status;
  console.log('error logging in: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
});
}
```

1. Most times, my API will throw a 'JWT not yet valid' error when attempting to validate the id-token with google. It seems to work once every 4 attempts.
2. and it's not hitting ngOnInit when navigating to 'companyList'

However, when I use the npm module sngular5-social-auth and implement the following code:

```
public socialSignIn(socialPlatform: string) {
let socialPlatformProvider;
socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;

this.socialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then(
  (userData) => {
    console.log(socialPlatform + " sign in data : ", userData);
    // store google user data in local storage
    localStorage.setItem('currentGoogleUserData', JSON.stringify(userData));

    this.userService.getUserByEmail(userData.email).subscribe(InUser => {
      this.globalService.setCurrentUser(InUser);
      this.router.navigate(['companylist']);
    }, error => {
      this.errorLoggingIn = true;
      this.errorCode = error.status;
      console.log('error logging in: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
);
}
```

all seems to work fine. I don't get the JWT not yet valid error and my company list page loads fine with data.

I've decided to go with option 1 because I get the default google sign in button.

any ideas what the difference between the 2 codes could be?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49696001/google-signin-access-token-vs-id-token-vs-code. If auth code is low traffic an easy fix can be sleeping for a small amount of time. I haven't looked at the source for angular5-social-auth but it's possible they have a custom clock implemented which is avoiding the issue you're having when calling the API directly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that your server time is different from Google server time. And when you validate received token from google it might be that token will be valid in 1 or n seconds. That's why you get an error `JWT not yet valid`

To fix it you can synchronize time of your server with google server time. Google doc how to do this is https://developers.google.com/time/

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the system time as per google or if your computer is part of a domain and you don't want to change the domain controller config, then you can pass a clock object in the Validateasync method like this:

```
var googleUser = await GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidateAsync(token, new GoogleJsonWebSignature.ValidationSettings()
            {
                Clock = new clock(),
                Audience = new[] { "your client id" }
            });
```

For this, you need to make a class implementing the IClock interface as below:

```
 public class clock : IClock
        {
            public DateTime Now => DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
    
            public DateTime UtcNow => DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5);
        }
```

In this, you can set the time accordingly like if my system time is 5 min. ahead of google time, I'll add 5 min., then your token will be successfully validated.

And to check the google time, you can make use of JwtSecurityTokenHandler class like:

```
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var tokenS = handler.ReadToken(token) as JwtSecurityToken;
```

in tokenS, you will have a property as issued at which will provide the UTC time, if you want local time then you can use `toLocal()` method on that property and compare that time to your system's time.